# Inequality in real numbers.

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers. If $a^2+b^2\leq2$ and $c^2+d^2\leq4$, the maximum value of the expression $ac+bd$ is?

How to proceed with it. I was given hint to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, but couldn't solve it.

Comment: Yes but please give a complete solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. By [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$(ac+bd)^2\leq (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2).$$
When does the equality holds? Note that $(ac+bd)^2\leq M$ implies that $-\sqrt{M}\leq ac+bd\leq \sqrt{M}$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the maximum value?

Comment: @sayan Would you mind to make a try?

Comment: It is continually comin $2√2$. I am not getting 3

Comment: Where does $3$ come from?

Comment: The answer key of the book says it is 3.

Comment: $2\sqrt{2}$ is the correct answer for the maximum. What about the minimum?

Comment: Minimum must be $-2√2$ . Am I correct??

Comment: Correct. To finish the exercise you should find $a,b,c,d$ such that $ac+bd=\pm2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By AM-GM,

$$ab+cd\leq\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}+\frac{c^2+d^2}{2}.$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$(ac+bd)^2\leq(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2).$$

Comment: It is $ac+bd$. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

By Causchy-Schwartz:

$$2\cdot 4\ge(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\ge(ac+bd)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

CS says that  $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\ge(ab+cd)^2$

Answer (score 0):

After using C-S we get a value $2\sqrt2$, which occurs for $(a,b)||(c,d)$, $|(ab)|=\sqrt2$ and $|(c,d)|=2$, which happens for $a=b=1$ and $c=d=\sqrt2$.

Thus, $2\sqrt2$ is the answer.

Comment: What does $(a,b)||(c,d)$ mean

Comment: @sayan It's just vector $(a,b)$ parallel to vector $(c,d)$.